# Trigger PHP after data is entered in a SAP system

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, sap-basis

I would like to start off by saying that am new to SAP and I've done my research but I just couldn't find a solution.

I have to update my database once a transaction has been entered on SAP. The output of this transaction is a txt file and I would like to automatically inject it into my database. I know the structure of the file and the directory where it's supposed to be. I also have a database where to inject it. What I am supposed to do is once the customer enters a transaction and the directory is updated with the latest txt file my script has to fetch that file and update database

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think the question doesn't have all the information. How/where is text file put? Is that a custom developed transaction? "Automatically" is a magic word, is there a DB table already for that with the same structure? Are you able to modify the program in question to have the data put in DB or you have to do it from outside somehow? In which part did you hit a dead end? Why does the question have "php" tag in it?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I know the structure of the file and the directory where it's supposed to be. I also have a database where to inject it. What am supposed to do is once the customer enters a transaction and the directory is updated with the latest txt file my script has to fetch that file and update database.

Comment: Please edit your question then. Also state that in what DB you want to insert the data. I feel that you have chosen php and mysql tags because you want to insert it outside the SAP DB, am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to insert it outside the SAP DB! I created a web application in which I am going to display the data with html/css and I used php/mysql to connect with DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with SAP sending data to the webserver. Possible and easy solution:

1, Create a receiver script on the webserver for example accepting POST request (with appropriate auth method). Accept file or array format. This script should insert / update entries to the database.

2, Create a program on the SAP side which fetches the right file from that directory and sends the file or formatted data in array to the webserver. Define a job for periodic processing.

Comment: Thank you for the help, really appreciate it :)